# Android keyboard hint shows android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner

Tags: android

I'm using a searchview with a custom suggestions adapter (a CursorAdapter) witch shows relevant suggestions.
When using the phone in landscape mode, the hint text changes when a suggestion is presented, but it shows the internal name (android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@66277f08), rather than the text from the textview. Clicking on it has the desired result so that's not the issue;

[image: android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@40571e90]

I guess i need to return the textview's content instead of the default behavior, but where should this take place?

Comment: are you using CursorAdapter?

Comment: and is it by any chance  SimpleCursorAdapter?

Comment: No a regular one (android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter)

Comment: tried to override convertToString(Cursor cursor)?

Comment: No I overlooked that methode somehow, tried some stuff in getItem. This actually worked! Thanks!